# Hibernate session successfully update object, but occasionally not

Tags: java, hibernate

I working with PostgreSQL in multithread mode by Hibernate sessions. Init:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

(other strings is connection URL and entity xml describe))

HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public static void close() {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    public static void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        sessionFactory = factory;
    }
}
```

All CRUD actions with Entities i do in separate class, where every action execute in one transaction.

```
public class SessionService {
    public static <T> T get(Class<T> classvar, int id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        T result = session.get(classvar, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }
    // Some other code
    public static void update(Object obj) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

There is no problems with multithreading work (or i not see it). But, some time ago i seen strange bug. I got one record from db by SessionService.get(Entity.class, 1). Change one field of this entity and save it by SessionService.update(entity). Update was successfull done without exceptions (logging approved). But changes not seen in database. In runtime entity has this changes, but not in db. I wait some time (for flush and others) but nothing changed. 
Tried to repeat bug - all good, bug not found. In one day i catch this bug on production server with 19 objects from 200, but in other days i not seen this bug.
Last importan moment: i don`t catched this bug with other entities (or i don`t see them).

What may be reason of it? May be better use entity manager instead sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the entire hibernate.cfg.xml file (delete the username and password of course).
Also are you 100% sure that you do not get an error like (wild guess) : 
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session ?

There are errors while running Hibernate, that literary flashes in the console for half a second when running queries. 
Had this problem a while back.